# Retreive-store from a Mule ObjectStore in Java

Tags: java, mule, mule-esb

I would like to retrieve and store from a mule ObjectStore in java. I could do a retreive operation separately and Store operation separately. But couldn't find a way to do them in the same operation.

I would need the equivalent of **objectstore:retrieve-store** operation in java.

Currently I am doing,

```
String expectedDelay= "expectedDelay";
ObjectStore<String> myObjStore = muleContext.getObjectStoreManager().getObjectStore("abcStore", true);
if (myObjStore.contains(expectedDelay)) {
    myObjStore.remove(expectedDelay);               
}
myObjStore.store(expectedDelay, delayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

if its object store v2, use the rest API

https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store/osv2-apis

If its custom object store, hit the database directly.